# Dependency-Wheel item without connection

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to add items that do not have connections ?

Tried setting the 'to' or 'weight' to empty or null, but that stops rendering the chart

https://www.highcharts.com/samples/codepen/highcharts/demo/dependency-wheel

Comment: Unfortunately, adding items without connection is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not supported, but you can hide some connections after creating the chart:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var points = this.series[0].points;

            points.forEach(function(point) {
                if (
                    point.from === 'Brazil' ||
                    point.to === 'Brazil'
                ) {
                    point.graphic.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tq2x4m1n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide